Seeking Review and Validation: Minimalist Arduino Mega Circuit Design
I've recently developed a minimalist circuit for the Arduino Mega with the intention of uploading the bootloader via SPI pins and utilizing a USB FTDI chip for programming.
Before proceeding further with my project, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in reviewing the attached schematic. My primary concern is to ensure that this minimalist setup aligns with my expectations and can be effectively utilized in my project.
Your expertise and feedback are invaluable to me, and any suggestions or insights you can provide would be immensely helpful in guiding me forward.

Thank you sincerely for your time and assistance.

"My primary concern is to ensure that this minimalist setup aligns with my expectations and can be effectively utilized in my project" - neither of which you've described. You need to ask a more focussed question that can be properly answered.

You can use the Arduino Mega schematic as a reference. One does wonder why you’d use a 20year old microcontroller with a high pin count, but not fan the pins out to connectors? I’d also challenge the economics considering you can buy cheapy mega clones for probably less than the cost of your pcb and BOM. As alternatives, you’ve got a whole world of choice out there. If your aim is large code size, but little gpio, then maybe something like the ESP32 is a cheaper, more performant and modern choice? Still with Arduino support , WiFi and Bluetooth.
